# Gridview not maintaining sort after paging

Tags: asp.net

All the help I've been able to find from similar posts regarding this issue isn't working for how I set up my GridView.

I've gotten my Gridview to have dynamically created columns, and was able to get sorting to work on it.  My paging works also, but if I sort first and then go to another page, it loses the sort.

What do I need to change in my Paging method to remember the sort?

Here is the code for the GridView:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Dim curLastName As New BoundField
        curLastName.HeaderText = "Last Name"
        curLastName.DataField = "LastName"
        curLastName.SortExpression = "LastName"
        GridView1.Columns.Insert(0, curLastName)

        Dim curFirstName As New BoundField
        curFirstName.HeaderText = "First Name"
        curFirstName.DataField = "FirstName"
        curFirstName.SortExpression = "FirstName"
        GridView1.Columns.Insert(1, curFirstName)

        Dim dt As DataTable = GetData().Tables(0)

        Dim dv As New DataView(dt)



        GridView1.DataSource = dv

        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetData() As DataSet

    Dim connectionstr As String

    connectionstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbConnectionString").ConnectionString.ToString()

    Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionstr)

    Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM EmployeeList where lastname like 'wil%'", myConnection)

    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    ad.Fill(ds)

    Return ds

End Function

Public Property GridViewSortDirection() As SortDirection


    Get


        If ViewState("sortDirection") Is Nothing Then

            ViewState("sortDirection") = SortDirection.Ascending
        End If


        Return DirectCast(ViewState("sortDirection"), SortDirection)
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As SortDirection)
        ViewState("sortDirection") = value
    End Set
End Property


Protected Sub GridView1_Sorting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewSortEventArgs)


    Dim sortExpression As String = e.SortExpression

    If GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending Then


        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending


        SortGridView(sortExpression, "DESC")
    Else



        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending


        SortGridView(sortExpression, "ASC")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub SortGridView(ByVal sortExpression As String, ByVal direction As String)

    Dim dt As DataTable = GetData().Tables(0)

    Dim dv As New DataView(dt)

    dv.Sort = sortExpression & " " & direction

    GridView1.DataSource = dv

    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub



Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As [Object], ByVal e As GridViewPageEventArgs)


    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex


    Dim dt As DataTable = GetData().Tables(0)

    Dim dv As New DataView(dt)



    GridView1.DataSource = dv

    GridView1.DataBind()



End Sub
```

The sorting and paging work, I'm just not sure what I have to change in my paging method to remember the sort.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should only use one `GetData` method which should take the sortexpression as parameter(just as your SortGridView). This must be called from PageIndexChanging and Sorting(and from page_load if not ispostback).

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim.  I'm still learning all of this so I'm unsure how to implement this advice.  I see how SortGridView is getting it's parameters, but I'm not sure how I'd be getting the values to pass to GetData for each instance.  Can you describe what I need to change a little further?  Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complete sample code including paging,sorting and databinding:

```
Sub Page_load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        CreateGridColumns()
        BindGrid()
    End If
End Sub

Public Property SortExpression As String
    Get
        If ViewState("SortExpression") Is Nothing Then
            ViewState("SortExpression") = "LastName ASC"
        End If
        Return ViewState("SortExpression").ToString
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        ViewState("SortExpression") = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub CreateGridColumns()
    Dim curLastName As New BoundField
    curLastName.HeaderText = "Last Name"
    curLastName.DataField = "LastName"
    curLastName.SortExpression = "LastName"
    GridView1.Columns.Insert(0, curLastName)

    Dim curFirstName As New BoundField
    curFirstName.HeaderText = "First Name"
    curFirstName.DataField = "FirstName"
    curFirstName.SortExpression = "FirstName"
    GridView1.Columns.Insert(1, curFirstName)
End Sub

Private Sub BindGrid()
    Try
        Dim tblData = New DataTable
        Using sqlCon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbConnectionString").ConnectionString.ToString())
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM EmployeeList ORDER BY {0}"
            Dim sqlCmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
            sqlCmd.CommandText = String.Format(sql, Me.SortExpression)
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon
            Using objAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
                objAdapter.Fill(tblData)
            End Using
        End Using
        GridView1.DataSource = tblData 
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' TODO: log error '
        throw
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView1.PageIndexChanging
    Me.GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    BindGrid()
End Sub

Private Sub GridView1_Sorting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles GridView1.Sorting
    Dim currentSortColumn, currentSortDirection As String
    currentSortColumn = Me.SortExpression.Split(" "c)(0)
    currentSortDirection = Me.SortExpression.Split(" "c)(1)
    If e.SortExpression.Equals(currentSortColumn) Then
        ' switch sort direction '
        Select Case currentSortDirection.ToUpper
            Case "ASC"
                Me.SortExpression = currentSortColumn & " DESC"
            Case "DESC"
                Me.SortExpression = currentSortColumn & " ASC"
        End Select
    Else
        Me.SortExpression = e.SortExpression & " ASC"
    End If
    BindGrid()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I really appreciate it!  I added the lines in my Page_Load to insert the FirstName and LastName columns.  (The first 10 lines in my original Page_Load).  The issue I'm having now is that the columns will sort and will page properly, but if I click a column to re-sort it from Desc to Asc, it doesn't seem to do it.  Is there something else I need to change.  Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: @Cineno: I've added the method to create the columns two minutes ago ;)  Have you adapted **all** of my code? Debug `GridView1_Sorting`.

Comment: thanks again for the help.  I used the code you provided, however when I tried to run it I got a message saying PageIndexChanging and Sorting couldn't be Private, so I changed them to Public to get it to run.  Is that ok? Sorry if it's an amateur question I'm new to this.  I debugged Sorting by stepping through it. If I'm following it right it may be called twice, so while trying to change a Desc to a Asc, it's going back to Desc.

Comment: @Cineno28: In VB.NET they can be private when you add the handles keyword(i think you've missed it in my code). Then you don't need to add the event handler on the aspx page. I assume that you only need to remove the declarative handler on aspx(`OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"`).

Comment: That was it! I changed them back to private and removed the OnSorting, and PagingIndex lines from the aspx and now it works!  Thanks so much for all your help and for staying to help!

Comment: I think the issue you've described is exactly [this](http://waxtadpole.wordpress.com/2009/03/23/gridview-sorting-event-handler-called-twice-on-one-onsorting-event/), hence my advice to remove either the `handles` in codebehind or the declaration in aspx markup was correct.

Comment: @JayaPrakashRokkam: You can ask a question with your code. Then i'll have a look when i've time. Leave a link here if you want.

Comment: @TimSchmelter My problem is that the state of the sorting results are not maintained when I fire the pageIndexChanging event. They get restored back to previous results. What do i do?

Answer (score 0):

After the "business" decided that a Web Forms application with gridview needed a specific "Page 2 for incidents etc..."  With ALL the EVENTS, postbacks, REDIRECTS etc... I have come to the liberating conclusion.

1. I'm not maintaining this application for some heavy hit company with large amount of traffic  (hence my solution with using database)
2. Sessions are not great for time-out and using 2 Nodes for server round robin
3. Hidden Fields will be lost on various actions
4. ViewState gets lost on various actions
5. Cookies are not going to work with users using different computers
6. Querystring  - ugly and some issues with it.

My solution wish is nothing genius is to skip all this and save string of important data into a database table in json.

I realize this is not something everyone wants to do, but in various situations as with mine.  It is so refreshing to not have tons of logic checking and setting ViewState etc..